# Strange titles (and bookmarks) in chromium in xubuntu

Tags: chrome, xubuntu, window-title

Chromium browser in xubuntu doesn't show Persian titles.

For example this site: www.farsnews.com

Screenshot (just title):
[image]

How can I fix that?

Edit:
I noticed it happens in bookmarks too.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: What locale are you using?

Comment: Does it happen only for this site or for others? Does it also happen with sites in Arabic? Does it also happen with sites in some other non-Latin script such as Chinese or Japanese? Does it happen in incognito windows?

Comment: @Gilles It's the same with every Persian or Arabic web site, I tested. It doesn't show anything on title in Chinese web sites.

Comment: I installed Google Chrome, and I have the same problem there.